# In Perl, what is the difference between `use lib` and `lib->import`?

Tags: perl

In Perl 5.24.1 what is the difference between using `use lib` and `lib->import`?
I see both used to add a directory to `@INC`.
I am using stock Perl with no add-ons.
I have read
http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html
and I do not understand much about all the ways how it's used.

Here is an example:

In the following sample code the first one `use lib` always works while the second one `lib->import` fails in my code I see it work in other code on the same machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use strict;
# new perl 2.24.1 requires FindBin
use FindBin;
print "found: $FindBin::Bin\n";
#This always works:
#use lib $FindBin::Bin;
#why does this not always work?
#lib->import($FindBin::Bin);

foreach my $var(@INC){
    print "$var \n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use lib EXPR` loads lib.pm, and at compile time, calls `lib->import(EXPR)`.

Just doing `lib->import(EXPR)` will do the same thing, except that if lib.pm has not been loaded, it will do nothing.  (Method calls to import() or unimport() are just ignored if there is no such sub.)  But it will be executed at run time, unless you have it in a BEGIN block, which means the change to @INC will not be performed in time to affect a later `use`.

Answer (score 3):

```
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
```

will do this (approximately):

```
BEGIN { require "lib.pm"; lib->import($FindBin::Bin); }
```

which both loads/compiles lib.pm and calls import *at compile time* (thus the BEGIN block).

When you call `lib->import(...)` by itself, this works, but only if lib is already loaded *and* whatever you're "importing" makes sense at runtime vs compile time.  With lib's import, this works fine, but only affects future `require` (or `eval "use ..."`) calls.  For other packages, if you're trying to import things like functions, this can be nonsensical, especially if those functions have a prototype that affects compile-time resolution.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.